# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor Concatenation With Html.Helpers And JQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, html-helper

So basically what I am trying to accomplish is within my JQuery template I am conditionally adding html helper controls as applicable, what seems to be giving me trouble is the right razor syntax to use the client side value of `$value.SomeUniqueId` as the ID for this server side generated control...

It will work if I use a static id as a literal like I am doing with the style; but I want to use an value I am feeding into the JQuery Template within and `{{each items}}...{{/each}}` block

E.G.:

```
{{each items}}
  {{if $value.IsAllowed }}                
    @Html.TextArea("txtSomeValue", new {style="width:80%", ID=$value.SomeUniqueId})
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

The offending line is: `@Html.TextArea("txtSomeValue", new {style="width:80%", ID=$value.SomeUniqueId})`

If I do this:`@Html.TextArea("txtSomeValue", new {style="width:80%", ID="someID"})...`
it works...

seem to be missing something obvious with the concatenation...

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mixing server-side and clientside code.

Comment: The value of ID must be a c# expression.

Comment: this is what I want to do... before razor this was not a problem, I had no problems concatenating server & client side values as applicable... it seems like I am stuck with server side values or static values after the @ with razor... I am looking for a way around that...

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to set up this textarea manually—without Razor:

```
<textarea name="txtSomeValue" style="width:80%;">${value.SomeUniqueId}</textarea>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, you want value.SomeUniqueId to be the textarea's id.  This *may* work

```
<textarea name="txtSomeValue" id="${value.SomeUniqueId}" style="width:80%;"></textarea>
```

Comment: yeah, I found that worked previously as well, but I need a unique identifier for the conditionally, dynamically added controls...

Comment: @user1011144 - why do you need a unique identifier?  You can leave off id's on html elements

Comment: for the sake of example... in the case of the text box there can be n number of text boxes, each of which will have unique, different values entered in them; I need to post all that back when validation is successful.

Comment: so you don't think I can use a razor html.helper in which I feed the unique identifier in via jquery/json when its rendered dynamically? I have no problem using the razor html.helper in the jquery template, but I cannot seem to mix and match server side & client side code like before razor...

Comment: @user1011144 - right, you can use it, but the server side razor method isn't going to accept client-side template values.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value as a string:

```
{{each items}}
  {{if $value.IsAllowed }}                
    @Html.TextArea("txtSomeValue", new {style="width:80%", ID="$value.SomeUniqueId"})
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```